# UIButtons not working on programmatically created UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` which I want to display a `UIView` that renders as a menu. This menu will have several buttons on it. I wanted to reuse this menu a few different places in my app so I figured I would create a class called `ViewFactory` that has a method that returns a `UIView` with these buttons.

On my `ViewController` I call this method and get the returned `UIView` and add it as a subview.

This works just fine. I can see the view and all its buttons, however, the buttons do not respond to any touch events. Not sure why this is the case and curious to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code for the `ViewFactoryClass`:

```
- (UIView *) addCloseRow
{
    // UIView container for everything else.
    UIView *navRow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,225,350,45)];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [navRow addSubview:button];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonTouchDownEvent) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    navRow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return navRow;
}
```

In my main `NavigationController` class  here is how I am calling and getting the `UIView`:

```
ViewFactory *factory = [[ViewFactory alloc] init];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:[factory MainNavigationUIView]];
```

Again, the `UIView` shows up but the buttons never respond to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the button with target and selector for `ViewFactoryClass`

And now you are creating instance and trying to call an action from `ViewFactory` class.

You can change the method to something like this:

```
- (UIView *) addCloseRow : (id)object {
    ...
    [button addTarget:[object class] action:@selector(closeButtonTouchDownEvent) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    ...
}
```

Comment: That fixed it Anoop! When updating my method to pass in the object I was able to click the button. After updating the method I went back to my NavigationViewController and passed in the class like so: `[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:[factory MainNavigationUIView:self]];`